# how can I delete alphanumeric rows from a column in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose my column name is "psdi", i want to print only numeric rows

```
psdi
100
10k
103f
456
9o2u
125
931
```

Required O/P:

```
psdi
100
456
125
```

Comment: please give me a query for above asked ques.Thanks

Comment: The stated duplicate is way overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two simple methods.  One looks for letters:

```
select t.*
from t
where not psdi ~ '[a-zA-Z]'
```

or for just digits:

```
select t.*
from t
where not psdi ~ '^[0-9]+$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern matching in where clause

`'^-?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$'` - This selects all type of values(positive, negative and floating values)

```
select *
from (
    values ('100T')
          ,('456.5')
          ,('-65')
          ,('9879t')
          ,('454')
    ) t(a)
where a ~ '^-?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$'
```

[`demo`](http://rextester.com/MZZJW50189)

---

Your query will be

```
select psdi
from your_table
where psdi ~ '^-?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$'
```